# What color can I spray on top my green bike?

Tags: frames, repair, paint

I want to do this without having to remove/strip having to strip paint from the frame which is already flaking off slowly.

Comment: Are you thinking of spraying your bike for better looks or to protect if from corrosion? Anyway, the color of paint doesn't substantially change whether you would need to strip paint or not. It's more about preparing the surface (clean, clear of oil, grease etc) and picking a suitable type/grade of paint.

Comment: if your paint is already flaking, there is pretty much zero point repainting without stripping it back first.

Comment: @pateksan just corrosion on the frame big spots where original paint is flaked off already. Maybe I can use another green paint to get uniform green look.

Comment: Guessing you're more looking for patching rather than complete paint job, still need to remove the flaking paint and prep either way.  Depends on how much patching you need, maybe a little nail vanish, or color match an Automotive touch-up pen

Answer (score 6):

If you don't do the preparation work, your paint will fail in short order regardless of colour.

The old saying about **Preparation being 99% of the work** is absolutely true.  New Paint will not stick to the frame if the old paint is between them and flaking off.

The process for a good paint finish would be to strip the bike of all components and wash all oils off.   Then remove all the loose old paint,  treat any rust and then sand any remaining well-adhered paint to add tooth as well as smoothing the transitions.

Only then can you start with primer coat on bare metal, then thin colour coats, and finally clear-coats on top.  Remember to let each layer dry according to the manufacturer's instructions, and to lightly scuff each layer just before wiping down and applying the next coat.    Fine/thin layers are your goal.

Once the last coat has had a week to harden then reassembly can commence.

Anything less is a waste of paint and your results will be sub-optimal.

If you haven't got the time for all this then consider a **wrap** instead.  Tape will go on much quicker and will hold all the loose paint in place.  Downside is tape wraps can accelerate rust by holding moisture against the frame.   Last resort is simply buy a bike in the colour you desire.

Answer (score 1):

The color of choice depends on your favorite color, since it is very hard to color match. It's not like a car where you can find the color code easily. Personally I like the blue/green dual color look; green/black also looks good.

If you spray over your slowly flaking paint, it can start to slowly flake again next year or so depending on how you expose it.  (It even may last a long time too.)  If you want to do it properly where the paint stays on for years and years, you need to prepare the frame, including stripping flaking paint.